# How to run specific queries from a list of queries in a table from HTML-PhP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql-server

I have 2 MySQL tables which have 2 identical columns, one is `temptable` and the other is `permanenttable`. I am displaying contents of `temptable` to a `php` form in the form of a table. In this form, I want that for every entry, I should have 2 options, `Approve` and `Revoke`. What I wish to do is if I click on `Approve`, the data of that row from `temptable` moves to `permanenttable`, or if I click on `Revoke`, the row from the `temptable` gets deleted. 
I am not getting an idea how to implement it. Here is what the form looks like : [image: php form template]

What I am initially trying to do is on click of Approve, I process the SQL queries, and then redirect back to this page, and when this page opens up again, the row in which we pressed a button gets erased(since it is being taken from `temptable`).

I am easy with the SQL queries, but I do not understand how to pass data to the next php file such that I can recognize which row to work on.

Also, any other suggestions on how this can be achieved will be very helpful!

Edit 1 : Tried Code - Form :

```
    $query = "SELECT * from adddoctor";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $pusername = $row['pusername'];
        $dusername = $row['dusername'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$pusername."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$dusername."</td>";
        echo "<form method = \"post\" action=\"approve.php\"">";
        echo "<td><input name=\"Approve".md5($pusername + $dusername)."\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Approve\"/></form>";
        echo "<form method = \"post\" action=\"revoke.php\">";
        echo "<input name=\"Revoke".md5($pusername + $dusername)."\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Revoke\"/></td></form>";
        echo "</tr>";
        ++$i;
    }
```

Approve :

```
$query = "Select * from adddoctor";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $pusername = $row['pusername'];
            $dusername = $row['dusername'];
            $hash =  md5( $pusername + $dusername);
            $hash = "Approve" + $hash;
            if(isset($_POST[$hash])){
                $query = "INSERT INTO pdmap values('$pusername','$dusername')";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                $query = "Delete from adddoctor where pusername = '$pusername' and dusername = '$dusername'";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can use PHP sessions.

Comment: @gladsocc can you please elaborate?

Comment: @SahilArora You could make each row a HTML form, then use POST to do what you need (treat both buttons as submits, but do different things for each button). Have you tried any code yet? If so, please share it with us! :)

Comment: @Qirel I exactly tried the same. Posted the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `+` to concatenate in php use `.`. In php `'text' + 'text' = 0` I think you are confusing javascript and php.

Form :

```
$query = "SELECT * from adddoctor";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $pusername = $row['pusername'];
    $dusername = $row['dusername'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$pusername."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$dusername."</td>";
    echo "<form method = \"post\" action=\"approve.php\"">";
    echo "<td><input name=\"Approve".md5($pusername . $dusername)."\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Approve\"/></form>";
    echo "<form method = \"post\" action=\"revoke.php\">";
    echo "<input name=\"Revoke".md5($pusername . $dusername)."\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Revoke\"/></td></form>";
    echo "</tr>";
    ++$i;
}
```

Approve :

```
$query = "Select * from adddoctor";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $pusername = $row['pusername'];
    $dusername = $row['dusername'];
    $hash =  md5( $pusername . $dusername);
    $hash = "Approve" . $hash;
    if(isset($_POST[$hash])){
        $query = "INSERT INTO pdmap values('$pusername','$dusername')";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $query = "Delete from adddoctor where pusername = '$pusername' and dusername = '$dusername'";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got messed up with the syntax. Working well and good now!